# Empty collection after fetch in Titanium app

Tags: api, rest, collections, titanium, titanium-alloy

On Titanium, I have the following files:

controllers/tab_matches.js

```
var matches = Alloy.Collections.match;
matches.fetch();

console.log(matches);
```

models/match.js

```
var Alloy = require("alloy");
exports.definition = {
  config : {
    "URL" : "http://" + Alloy.CFG.server.ip + ":" + Alloy.CFG.server.port + "/api/matches/",
    "debug" : Alloy.CFG.debug,
    "adapter" : {
      "type" : "restapi",
      "collection_name" : "matches",
      "idAttribute" : "id"
    }
  },
  extendModel : function(Model) {
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {});
    return Model;
  },
  extendCollection : function(Collection) {
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {});
    return Collection;
  }
}
```

views/tab_matches.xml

```
<Alloy>
  <Collection src="match" />
  <Window title="Matches">
    <ListView id="list_matches">
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

For the REST API, I use this one: https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi

Why is my collection empty after the fetch call? Unable to loop into matches and matches.length is 0.

Here is the log and, as we can see, one element is returned from the remote server.

```
[INFO] :   [REST API] options:
[INFO] :   {
[INFO] :       error = "<KrollCallback: 0xad60b20>";
[INFO] :       headers =     {
[INFO] :           "Content-Type" = "application/json";
[INFO] :       };
[INFO] :       parse = 1;
[INFO] :       success = "<KrollCallback: 0xad60ac0>";
[INFO] :       type = GET;
[INFO] :       url = "http://192.168.1.10:3000/api/matches/";
[INFO] :   }
[INFO] :   {
[INFO] :       "_byCid" =     {
[INFO] :       };
[INFO] :       "_byId" =     {
[INFO] :       };
[INFO] :       "_onModelEvent" = "<KrollCallback: 0x138742d0>";
[INFO] :       "_prepareModel" = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388f140>";
[INFO] :       "_removeReference" = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388c220>";
[INFO] :       "_reset" = "<KrollCallback: 0x1387c9f0>";
[INFO] :       add = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386bcd0>";
[INFO] :       all = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386cef0>";
[INFO] :       any = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386d900>";
[INFO] :       at = "<KrollCallback: 0x13882900>";
[INFO] :       bind = "<KrollCallback: 0x13881310>";
[INFO] :       chain = "<KrollCallback: 0x13877890>";
[INFO] :       config =     {
[INFO] :           Model = "<KrollCallback: 0x13876d80>";
[INFO] :           URL = "http://192.168.1.10:3000/api/matches/";
[INFO] :           adapter =         {
[INFO] :               "collection_name" = matches;
[INFO] :               idAttribute = id;
[INFO] :               type = restapi;
[INFO] :           };
[INFO] :           debug = 1;
[INFO] :       };
[INFO] :       constructor = "<KrollCallback: 0x1387f0d0>";
[INFO] :       contains = "<KrollCallback: 0x138803d0>";
[INFO] :       create = "<KrollCallback: 0x13873f50>";
[INFO] :       detect = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388d530>";
[INFO] :       each = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386c070>";
[INFO] :       every = "<KrollCallback: 0x13884b30>";
[INFO] :       fetch = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386c140>";
[INFO] :       filter = "<KrollCallback: 0x13883d80>";
[INFO] :       find = "<KrollCallback: 0x138815f0>";
[INFO] :       first = "<KrollCallback: 0x1387f5a0>";
[INFO] :       forEach = "<KrollCallback: 0x13887180>";
[INFO] :       get = "<KrollCallback: 0x1387e690>";
[INFO] :       getByCid = "<KrollCallback: 0x13881290>";
[INFO] :       groupBy = "<KrollCallback: 0x13884fa0>";
[INFO] :       idAttribute = id;
[INFO] :       include = "<KrollCallback: 0x13882090>";
[INFO] :       indexOf = "<KrollCallback: 0x13883840>";
[INFO] :       initial = "<KrollCallback: 0x13888180>";
[INFO] :       initialize = "<KrollCallback: 0x1385a300>";
[INFO] :       invoke = "<KrollCallback: 0x138803f0>";
[INFO] :       isEmpty = "<KrollCallback: 0x138844b0>";
[INFO] :       last = "<KrollCallback: 0x13870460>";
[INFO] :       lastIndexOf = "<KrollCallback: 0x13884c30>";
[INFO] :       length = 0;
[INFO] :       map = "<KrollCallback: 0x13887ca0>";
[INFO] :       max = "<KrollCallback: 0x13884cf0>";
[INFO] :       min = "<KrollCallback: 0x13884d50>";
[INFO] :       model = "<KrollCallback: 0x13858ad0>";
[INFO] :       models =     (
[INFO] :       );
[INFO] :       off = "<KrollCallback: 0x13887100>";
[INFO] :       on = "<KrollCallback: 0x138870e0>";
[INFO] :       parse = "<KrollCallback: 0x138754c0>";
[INFO] :       pluck = "<KrollCallback: 0x13886c00>";
[INFO] :       pop = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386dcc0>";
[INFO] :       push = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386dca0>";
[INFO] :       reduce = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388d110>";
[INFO] :       reduceRight = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388d510>";
[INFO] :       reject = "<KrollCallback: 0x13884b10>";
[INFO] :       remove = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386bcf0>";
[INFO] :       reset = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388f120>";
[INFO] :       rest = "<KrollCallback: 0x138881e0>";
[INFO] :       select = "<KrollCallback: 0x13883de0>";
[INFO] :       shift = "<KrollCallback: 0x1387e670>";
[INFO] :       shuffle = "<KrollCallback: 0x138838c0>";
[INFO] :       size = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386d9d0>";
[INFO] :       some = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386cf50>";
[INFO] :       sort = "<KrollCallback: 0x13886be0>";
[INFO] :       sortBy = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388d480>";
[INFO] :       sortedIndex = "<KrollCallback: 0x13886210>";
[INFO] :       sync = "<KrollCallback: 0x13859d80>";
[INFO] :       toArray = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386d9b0>";
[INFO] :       toJSON = "<KrollCallback: 0x1385a320>";
[INFO] :       trigger = "<KrollCallback: 0x138874d0>";
[INFO] :       unbind = "<KrollCallback: 0x1388c2c0>";
[INFO] :       unshift = "<KrollCallback: 0x1386ccc0>";
[INFO] :       where = "<KrollCallback: 0x13882920>";
[INFO] :       without = "<KrollCallback: 0x13876b20>";
[INFO] :   }
[INFO] :   [REST API] server read response:
[INFO] :   (
[INFO] :           {
[INFO] :           id = 3;
[INFO] :           lastminute = 0;
[INFO] :           opengroup = 1;
[INFO] :       }
[INFO] :   )
```

Comment: Your model has no columns, so therefore doesnt store any data, have you tried adding columns?

Comment: Hi. I tried, but the length is still 0, either with or without columns.

Comment: Did you actually add models to the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing something like the following code.

fetch is an async call, so the collection was empty right after the call. Results have to be processed in the success callback.

```
matches.fetch({
    success: function(){
        console.log(matches.models);
        //parse to listView
        var data = [];
        _.each(matches.models, function(element, index, list){
            data.push(
                Alloy.createController("ListItem", {
                    title : element.attributes['title'] //whatever you need to set
                }).getView()
            );
        });
        // add to your listview
    },
    error: function(){
        // something is wrong.. 
    }
});
```

Thanks to Mads Moller: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153642/empty-collection-after-fetch